# SortList duplicated key, but it shouldn't

Tags: c#, sorting, duplicates

I have a class which implements IList interface. I requires a "sorted view" of this list, but without modifying it (I cannot sort directly the IList class).

These view shall be updated when the original list is modified, keeping items sorted. So, I've introduced a SortList creation method which create a SortList which has a comparer for the specific object contained in the original list.

Here is the snippet of code:

```
public class MyList<T> : ICollection, IList<T> 
{
    public SortedList CreateSortView(string property)
    {
        try
        {
            Lock();

            SortListView sortView;

            if (mSortListViews.ContainsKey(property) == false)
            {
                // Create sorted view
                sortView = new SortListView(property, Count);
                mSortListViews.Add(property, sortView);

                foreach (T item in Items)
                    sortView.Add(item);
            } else
                sortView = mSortListViews[property];

            sortView.ReferenceCount++;
            return (sortView);
    }
    finally
    {
        Unlock();
    }
}

public void DeleteSortView(string property)
{
    try
    {
        Lock();

        // Unreference sorted view
        mSortListViews[property].ReferenceCount--;
        // Remove sorted view
        if (mSortListViews[property].ReferenceCount == 0)
            mSortListViews.Remove(property);
    }
    finally
    {
        Unlock();
    }
}

protected class SortListView : SortedList
{
    public SortListView(string property, int capacity)
        : base(new GenericPropertyComparer(typeof(T).GetProperty(property, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)), capacity)
    {               
    }

    public int ReferenceCount = 0;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Add(item, item);
    }

    public void Remove(T item)
    {
        base.Remove(item);
    }

    class GenericPropertyComparer : IComparer
    {
        public GenericPropertyComparer(PropertyInfo property)
        {
            if (property == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("property doesn't specify a valid property");
            if (property.CanRead == false)
                throw new ArgumentException("property specify a write-only property");
            if (property.PropertyType.GetInterface("IComparable") == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("property type doesn't IComparable");

            mSortingProperty = property;
        }

        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            IComparable propX = (IComparable)mSortingProperty.GetValue(x, null);
            IComparable propY = (IComparable)mSortingProperty.GetValue(y, null);
            return (propX.CompareTo(propY));
        }

        private PropertyInfo mSortingProperty = null;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, SortListView> mSortListViews = new Dictionary<string, SortListView>();
}
```

Practically, class users request to create a SortListView specifying the name of property which determine the sorting, and using the reflection each SortListView defined a IComparer which keep sorted the items.
Whenever an item is added or removed from the original list, every created SortListView will be updated with the same operation.

This seems good at first chance, but it creates me problems since it give me the following exception when adding items to the SortList:

> System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'PowerShell_ISE [C:\Windows\sysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell_ISE.exe]'  Key being added: 'PowerShell_ISE [C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell_ISE.exe]'

As you can see from the exception message, thrown by `SortedListView.Add(object)`, the string representation of the key (the list item object) is different (note the path of the executable).

Why SortList give me that exception?

To solve this I tried to implement a `GetHashCode()` for the underlying object, but without success:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return (
        base.GetHashCode() ^
        mApplicationName.GetHashCode() ^
        mApplicationPath.GetHashCode() ^
        mCommandLine.GetHashCode() ^ 
        mWorkingDirectory.GetHashCode()
    );
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say that this happens only with some object values (about the 5%). So, while the original list contains 100 items, the "sorted views" contains only 95 items.

Comment: Could't you try to debug your `GenericPropertyComparer` by setting a breakpoint when `propX.CompareTo(propY)` returns 0 ? So you will able to understand if the comparer is working correct and if values are actually equals...

Comment: @digEmAll You got the point! I noticed that IComparable.CompareTo doesn't call GetHashCode! Ouch! I need some clarification about the SortList IComparer function. Now I understand why everyone try to duplicate keys in SortList: they want sort on keys, which can be duplicated (in my case, the view "ApplicationName" is duplicated, but not "ApplicationPath").

Comment: Minor feedback on your locking - if this fails before or during lock acquisition (a far-corner-case) you try to release a lock you don't have. This is unrelated to the question posed - just something to note.

Comment: @Marc Gravell I've never considered the case Monitor.Enter fails (just throw ArgumenNullException). How could it be?

Comment: @Luca - search for a blog post by Eric Lippert; locks and exceptions do not mix

Comment: Quoting: "And of course, this is yet another reason why aborting a thread is pure evil. Try to never do so!". Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, your purpose is just to get a view of you list, sorted by a property of the object.

Then, why use `SortedList` that requires unique Keys, when you could easily get your result using LINQ `OrderBy` (or if you're using .net 2.0 `List.Sort()`) ?

Hence, for example, your `CreateSortView` could be implemented in this way:
(omitting lock, try/finally and reference counting)

```
public IList<T> CreateSortView(string property)
{
    IList<T> sortView;
    if (mSortListViews.ContainsKey(property) == false)
    {
        // Create sorted view
        sortView = this.OrderBy(x => x, new GenericPropertyComparer<T>(property)).ToList();
        mSortListViews.Add(property, sortView);
    }
    else
    {
        sortView = mSortListViews[property];
    }
    return sortView;
}
```

With `GenericPropertyComparer` implemented as follows:

```
class GenericPropertyComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    public GenericPropertyComparer(string propertyName)
    {
        var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        if (property == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("property doesn't specify a valid property");
        if (property.CanRead == false)
            throw new ArgumentException("property specify a write-only property");
        if (property.PropertyType.GetInterface("IComparable") == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("property type doesn't IComparable");

        mSortingProperty = property;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        IComparable propX = (IComparable)mSortingProperty.GetValue(x, null);
        IComparable propY = (IComparable)mSortingProperty.GetValue(y, null);

        return (propX.CompareTo(propY));
    }

    private PropertyInfo mSortingProperty = null;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you need to add/remove items from your sorted collection frequeltly, maybe use a SortedList would be better, but the problem with SortedList is that it needs unique keys, and in your case you can't assure that.

Anyway, you can use a custom sorted List that doesn't need unique values, look at the link below for a simple implementation:

[Implementation of sorted `IList<T>` that doesn't require unique values](http://pastebin.com/c79BGJXM)

Comment: Edited according to your comment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me it is a multithreading issue. I can't see what the Lock() function is doing in your code, but I think you will have more luck by surrounding the dictionary access code with a standard lock:

```
lock(this){
SortListView sortView;
if (mSortListViews.ContainsKey(property) == false) {
            // Create sorted view
            sortView = new SortListView(property, Count);
            mSortListViews.Add(property, sortView);

            foreach (T item in Items)
                sortView.Add(item);
        } else
            sortView = mSortListViews[property];
        sortView.ReferenceCount++;

 }
```

and the same in the removing part.

Comment: The data is actually accessed by a single thread (at least on the process which creates the views). You code is almost equivalent, since **Lock()** routine does **Monitor.Enter(SyncRoot)**, but allows me to scope the exclusive object access in a more complex manner.

Comment: In any case, mSortListView has a key of type string, don't understand which dictionary is using the object you provided a custom gethashcode as a key. Anyway, calling base on gethashcode is not a good idea since you have to hash just the meaningfull properties.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to *digEmAll*'s comment, I found a quick solution: The IComparer implementation shall return 0 only on objects really equals!

So:

```
public int Compare(object x, object y)
{
    IComparable propX = (IComparable)mSortingProperty.GetValue(x, null);
    IComparable propY = (IComparable)mSortingProperty.GetValue(y, null);
    int compare;

    if ((compare = propX.CompareTo(propY)) == 0) {
        if (x.GetHashCode() < y.GetHashCode())
            return (-1);
        else if (x.GetHashCode() > y.GetHashCode())
            return (+1);
        else return (0);
    } else
        return (compare);
}
```

Comment: IMO using `GetHashCode` in a comparer seems a bit strange to me and probably wrong considering that `HashCode` can be equal for 2 different objects. Look at my answer for another solution.

Comment: Yeah. I changed the design: now the generic argument T shall derive from IComparable<T>, in order to avoid the GetHashCode() comparing.

Comment: @Luca: yes, that's better. Anyway, I still think that using a `SortedList` to get a list sorted by a single property of the items (with the complication of the key uniqueness constraint to solve), seems an overwork to me. It's simpler to sort the original list on demand IMO :)

Comment: Definitely depends on the frequency of added/removed elements (which requires a sort operation to have an updated "view").

Comment: Yes, if you add/remove frequently you're right. In that case a sortedlist is better. An other solution would be removing/adding using a binary search on the List you've sorted, so basically you'll get the same performances of a SortedList.